# Method to highlight a single row in an apex:dataTable

Tags: visualforce

I have a dataTable as part of a Visualforce component, and I'd like to write some code to have it highlight a single row of the table, based on some value in that row's data.

Recall that an `<apex:dataTable>` contains multiple `<apex:column>` values, and it does not use an `<apex:repeat>` to loop through records.  I would prefer to keep the dataTable for formatting reasons.

My current thought is whether I can include an `<apex:outputPanel>` that contains Javascript that can somehow find the parent `<tr>` of the current `<td>` and change its `background-color`.

Am I jumping through too many hoops?  Will such a method even work, and what would it look like?  Is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

My current workaround is an `<apex:outputPanel>` wrapping the text of a single cell, and setting the style to `background-color:#FFFF00` or an empty string.  It doesn't look good, and I'd prefer to highlight the entire row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this is something you are looking for :

[image]

I used style per column based on a specific name to highlight a single row of the table, based on some value in that row's data (assuming row data from one column !!!)

```
<apex:page Controller="account_multicolor" >
<style>
.value{
background-color: #FCF7F7;}
</style>
<apex:dataTable value="{!account_val}" var="acc" rowclasses="">
<apex:column headervalue="Id" value="{!acc.Id}" style="{!IF((acc.name ='TEST'),"background-color: #0000FF;","")}"/>
<apex:column headervalue="name" value="{!acc.name}" style="{!IF((acc.name ='TEST'),"background-color: #0000FF;","")}"/>
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a decent workaround.  I had hoped to create an `apex:variable` before the `apex:column` tags, and use that for the `style` attribute, but it didn't work.  I'm stuck with a copy of my big `IF()` in every column definition.

Comment: can y0u try using contains() (or) use  a static resource to manage all the keywords and refer it in the page??

Comment: I'm currently using `style="{!IF(highlight == s.streamName || highlight == s.streamId, 'background-color:#FFFFD0', '')}"` and don't think I can reduce it further, since I need to compare a fixed value against two separate fields of the row.