# Conditionally color a row in a pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

How do I conditionally hightlight a row in a pageBlockTable?

If a row meets a criteria, I want to highlight the row with a color ( #C1C01A).

I can't seem to get it. any suggestions?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myList}" var="myrow"  >

            </apex:column>
            <apex:repeat value="{!colHeaders}" var="headerForCol">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">{!headerForCol['fieldName']}</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="{!mymap[myrow].[headerForCol['sourceFieldName']]}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:repeat>


            <apex:column width="150px" >
                <apex:facet name="header">My Col</apex:facet>

            </apex:column>    

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Niv -- if you want to avoid having this question closed - you should post what you have tried so far; you should also look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12049/method-to-highlight-a-single-row-in-an-apexdatatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use styleClass with if condition.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highlight
    {
        background-color: #C1C01A;
        /* I think outputText users 
    }
</style>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myList}" var="myrow"  >


        </apex:column>
        <apex:repeat value="{!colHeaders}" var="headerForCol">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">{!headerForCol['fieldName']}</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLabel styleClass="{!IF(headerForCol['fieldName'] != Result, 'highlight', '')}" value="{!mymap[myrow].[headerForCol['sourceFieldName']]}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:repeat>


        <apex:column width="150px" >
            <apex:facet name="header">My Col</apex:facet>

        </apex:column>    

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>
```